# how to change dimensions of html5 canvas without it scaling content

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I init my canvas like this:

```
<canvas id="canvasDiv" width="20" height="20"></canvas>
```

and somewhere in the code I want to resize it to it's final size:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasDiv");
canvas.style.width = 200;
canvas.style.height = 100;
```

However, any pixel I plot on my canvas is scaled (so it's not 1 pixel anymore).

How does one change the dimensions of a canvas without this scaling effect? (So programmatically)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you just need to also set its width & height properties:

```
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 100;
```

Comment: wow... I actually checked some online DOM references to see the attributes of dom elements, and width and height were not on there. Other examples used this style trick. Thats why I used that syntax

Comment: Is there actually a proper/official dom/css reference guide?  I sued this one but apparently it is not complete: http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementproperties.shtml

Comment: The official spec for the canvas tag is at http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html