# How to perform selection on a canvas image?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

An image is added to this canvas:

```html
<canvas width="500" height="204.375" style="margin-top: -102.188px; margin-left: -250px;" data-caman-id="0"></canvas>
```

I need to perform a selection on this image in the canvas.
Like here : [Selection operation](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/)

This supports image only.I need it on canvas

How can selection of small portion to crop that portion or resize that or any other operation can be performed?
I tried jquery plugin but many of them supports image rather i had canvas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crop Canvas / Export html5 canvas with certain width and height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073647/crop-canvas-export-html5-canvas-with-certain-width-and-height)

Comment: Have You read it properly at first i need to perform selection operation on canvas.Seleting a portion on image.

Comment: Have read properly the second answer ? it refers to the `mousedown` event. So i you use `mousedown` et `mouseup`events to capture the starting point and the ending point, you'll have the desired zone to make the crop.

Comment: No i am not getting the way to select .Then i can use the mouse down.