# Guide to Crop uploaded images using React Konva

Tags: reactjs, canvas, konvajs, react-konva

I am using React Konva to upload images (multiple) to the stage and I want to implement crop uploaded functionality. Can anyone give me a guide/ steps ?

Comment: [This is a similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073647/crop-canvas-export-html5-canvas-with-certain-width-and-height), not using Konvajs but should be adaptable. Search SO for 'html5 canvas crop image' - there are many hits.

Comment: What did you try?