# How can I extract images from image

Tags: javascript, image, extract, crop, cropper

you can see in this image 2 parts are selected I want to save those selected parts as a 2 new images, this is the main purpose of this extracter it extract images from image

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C4rq.jpg)

can I build this using JavaScript

Comment: Yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073647/crop-canvas-export-html5-canvas-with-certain-width-and-height

Comment: hi,This is not what I am looking for,Look at that image