# How to resize html5 canvas without pixel blur

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, scale, blur

I am aware you can scale a canvas using css similar as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293727/how-to-change-dimensions-of-html5-canvas-without-it-scaling-content#_=_).  But I have a 24x24 pixel canvas I want to through css make 600 pixels wide.  The result of that is:

[Photo](http://i43.tinypic.com/fwhw8l.png)

Is there a method of doing this that will just display the pixels HUGE instead of blurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried [`scale`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_scale.asp) already?

```
canvas.scale(xScale, yScale);
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding that method properly.  When using any values other than 'canvas.scale(1, 1)' it no longer fits inside the canvas anymore.

Comment: Make the cancas 600x600 and import your 24x24 image and scale it by a factor 25.

Comment: I am not using a 24x24 image.  The image I linked is a screenshot of my canvas.  I am drawing the pixels manually.

Comment: Disregard that.  I wasn't thinking correctly.  Event though I am manually drawing pixels it worked the same.

Comment: Thank you! I use this a solution to down-scale screenshots made on retina display http://sourcebox.io/2ff7ea7f4fb03dde996c8194a1599b23/html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
canvas,
img {
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
    image-rendering: optimize-contrast;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering

Comment: this doesn't unblur it for me

Comment: Check this example in firefox http://jsfiddle.net/7uL2fhLk/1/,
in chrome don't work

Comment: if it doesn't work in Chrome, it won't work in Safari, Opera, Yandex, Maxthon, and many other Webkit- or Blink-based browsers